# ios force autolayout update on show keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, autolayout, ios9

So, I have this view that is just a wrapper for the happy pink photo that i want to center in the view. I've been using two spacing views in between the Top Layout Guide and the top of the view that wraps the textbox and the send button at the bottom of the screen (the white ones). From the picture below you can see that is working just fine.

[image]

Now, since this is going to be a "leave your comment" page, the user needs to pull the keyboard up, and the autolayout noeeds to be updated accordingly. I tried to call [self.view setNeedsLayout], [self.view updateConstraints], [self.view layoutIfNeeded], but none of them does the trick. All I have is this:

[image]

You might object that I did something wrong in the autolayout, but then when I rotate the screen, the layout updates as expected, resizing the 2 spacing views and keeping the happy pink picture in the center:

[image]

How can I trigger a layout update?? I'm going crazy!!

Please tell me if you need any more informations

Comment: resize you view when keyboard appear.

Comment: Just because maybe words can be deceiving, here's a picture of the effect that i'm trying to achieve: https://imgur.com/ckXEina

Comment: Can you show the constraints of the lower white UIView?

Comment: sure thing! http://imgur.com/wUkvFu1

Comment: it's like autolayout doesn't know that I'm moving the bottom view (in the project is called Controls View)

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons why the layout is not behaving the way you want, It could be the constraints that define the height of the two white UIViews, the priority of the vertical hugging or compression resistance of this views, etc, but I guess this two views can be the source of the problem.

So, if the only purpose of the two white UIViews is to centre the pink photo I would suggest you get rid of them, instead you can put the pink photo inside a single UIView and centre the photo with a couple of alignment constraints

[image: Image constraints]

As you can see there are two align to centre constraints for the imageView, and three more constraints that help in case you support landscape orientation, if you are in landscape orientation the image probably won't fit in the blue view so you can add two greater than constraints and an aspect ratio constraint.

Now, the light blue view that contains the image only have four constraints: leading, trailing, top and a horizontal space constraint to the textField wrapper, so when the keyboard appears and move the textField wrapper up, the containerView shrinks and the image moves to the centre.

Comment: Thank for taking time to answer me! I got rid of the 2 white views, but the issue persists. The wrapper view is basically from the top part of the screen until the top side of the textfied wrapper, there are both 2 vertical spacing costrain set to 0. Still, when I'm bringing the keyboard up (and succesfully moving the texfied wrapper view), the wrapping view with the picture still stays anchored to the bottom, like nothing happened... :(

Comment: How are you moving the textField wrapper view? Are you changing the constant of the constraint between this wrapper and the bottom layout guide?

Comment: mmm nope, i'm just calculating how tall the keyboard is and then adding the value to the frame origin... is there a step i'm missing?!

Comment: When you use auto layout you should always avoid changing the frame of views, you should always change the constraints instead; I made a gist of how I did it: https://gist.github.com/JuanjoArreola/a06d33e76eb61f22d1cf ,  `bottomConstraint` is the constraint between the textField wrapper and the bottom layout constraint

Comment: `bottomConstraint` is the constraint between the textField wrapper and the bottom layout *guide* not constraint

Comment: Tank you so very much! It worked! I was able to move the view up with the bottom guide constrain, it was so much easier than getting the fram and all... and it also moves the view with the picture!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add observers to notify you when the keyboard appears or disappears to adapt your view by the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then implement these methods.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification 
{ 
  CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size; 
  // the above is the keyboard size, implement prober view resizing as you wish, but i recommend a scrollview and you scroll it.
}
```

and then

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification 
{ 
  //get everything back to original size or set the scrollview content size back to block scrolling.
}
```

at the end don't forget to remove yourself from being an observer for the keyboard when the view disappears

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; 
}
```

Comment: I can already move the view with the textbox when the keyboard is being pulled up. My question regards the triggering of an autolayout update when the keyboard is shown in order to resize the 2 white view and the view with the picture in between

Comment: try to call  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: ... have you ever read what I wrote?!I clearly stated that I called that already.